# Puppeteer, problem performing event on element on specific site

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Been trying out puppeteer to login to a certain site but nothing I threw at it worked ... it's doing something really strange. Tried all kinds of clicks on element , moving mouse to the position of the element and doing mouse down / up , click , doing enter event from keyboard. Waiting for everything to load. I think there's something missing or the javascript is interpreted differently somehow inside the headless browser ?
Here's how it looks like after performing the login , screenshot took using puppeteer
[image]

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//const {installMouseHelper} = require('./install-mouse-helper');


async function run () {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
//await installMouseHelper(page);


await page.goto("https://dash.bdroppy.com/login?lang=EN", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

await page.waitFor('input[name=email]');

await page.$eval('input[name=email]', el => el.value = 'test@test.com');

await page.$eval('input[name=password]', el => el.value = 'abcdefg');

// const loginButton = await page.$('.AuthSubmit');
// const rect = await page.evaluate((loginButton) => {
//     const {top, left, bottom, right} = loginButton.getBoundingClientRect();
//     return {top, left, bottom, right};
//   }, loginButton);

//  const x = (rect.top + rect.right) / 2;
//  const y = (rect.left + rect.bottom) / 2;

// console.log(x,y);

// console.log(rect);

await page.mouse.move(290, 539);

await page.mouse.click(290, 539, { button: 'left' })

// console.log(await page.evaluate( async() => {
//     const loginbutton =  document.elementFromPoint(290, 533);
//     await page.waitFor(3000);
   
//     await page.mouse.down();

// await page.mouse.up();
    
//   }));

//await page.mouse.down();

//await page.mouse.up();



// await page.$$eval(selectors[0].click())


await page.waitFor(3000);

//await page.click('.AuthSubmit');
// await page.click('.AuthSubmit');



// await page.$eval('.AuthSubmit CC', el => {
//     console.log(el);
//     el.click()
// });

//await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

// await page.waitForNavigation();




await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});



//  page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
//         console.log(dialog.defaultValue());
//     // dialog.accept("Stack Overflow!");
// });



await browser.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: give a try to page.$x (xpath). get correct path and try

Comment: Hello sir. Couldn't reliably get the xpath for the login button also noticed the parent element changes on each refresh maybe in an attempt to thwart these kind of automations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I used input type. This will get input by name.

Tested and working fine.

```
await page.goto("https://dash.bdroppy.com/login?lang=EN", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

await page.waitFor('input[name=email]');

await page.type('input[name=email]', 'test comment', {delay: 20})

//await page.$eval('input[name=email]', el => el.value = 'test@test.com');

await page.type('input[name=password]', 'test comment', {delay: 20})

//add some delay here. This should work

await page.click('div[class="AuthSubmit CC "]');
```

Maybe parent element is changing but there is only one email/password input. We can use this.

Comment: Hello, I can't seem to submit it though , have any suggestion please ?

Comment: You mean you want to click button ?

Comment: Yes that is my intention.